# static generation in the latest version of Next JS is not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, azure-service-fabric

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc9Hs.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzvDS.png)

I just wanted to test routing but couldn't.
I used a new folder in components/about
and when I search with http://localhost:3000/components/about
failed teru
Likewise, I created it in the pa folder
I have tried to change the file name from the first letter capitalized to lowercase
Please help
it's been one week it hasn't worked either

> The resource http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js?ts=1677900209480 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Comment: I'm getting the same warning. Have you found a fix to it?